# Changing URL destination for "home" logo in OSCommerce

Tags: html, oscommerce, sts-simple-templatesystem

http://shop.auxout.com/

We're hosting the store on a virtual server for the time being. Can anyone tell me where I can edit OSComm so that the top AUX logo points to [www.auxout.com](http://www.auxout.com)?

Answer (score 0):

**In osCommerce v2.2**

File: `catalog/includes/header.php`

Around line 57 of a clean install find this line:

```
<td valign="middle"><?php echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT) . '">' .
  tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'store_logo.png', STORE_NAME) . '</a>'; ?></td>
```

**In osCommerce v3** (if you're working from the default template at least)

File: `templates/default.php`

Around line 264 of a clean install find this line:

```
echo osc_link_object(osc_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT), osc_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES .
 'store_logo.jpg', STORE_NAME), 'id="siteLogo"');
```

In both instances, simply edit the `FILENAME_DEFAULT` portion to where you would like the store logo to point to if other than the catalogue home.